# Reference request: Grothendieck groups of Hecke algebras at root of unity and symmetric functions

Tags: algebraic-combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, hecke-algebras, symmetric-functions

Let $\zeta$ be an $\ell^{\text{th}}$ root of unity, and consider $H_n(\zeta)$, the (finite) Hecke algebra of type A.  One can consider a dual pair of Hopf algebras arising from this data, denoted $G(\zeta)$ and $K(\zeta)$, where
$$
G(\zeta)=\bigoplus_{n\geq0}G_n(\zeta) \text{ and } K(\zeta)=\bigoplus_{n\geq0}K_n(\zeta). 
$$
Here $G_n(\zeta)$ is the Grothendieck group of the category of finitely generated left $H_n(\zeta)$-modules, and $K_n(\zeta)$ is the Grothendieck group of finitely generated projective left $H_n(\zeta)$-modules.  Induction and restriction endow these spaces with a bialgebra structure, which can be enhanced to a Hopf structure.

In "Hecke algebras at roots of unity and crystal cases of quantum affine algebras" Lascoux, Leclerc, and Thibon mention isomorphisms
$$
G(\zeta) \cong Sym/I \text{ and } K(\zeta) \cong I^{\perp}
$$ 
where $Sym$ is the algebra of symmetric functions, $I$ is the ideal generated by power sum symmetric functions $p_\ell,p_{2\ell},p_{3\ell},...$, and the complement is taken with respect to the standard inner product on $Sym$ (see page 215 of [LLT]).

My question: does anybody know a reference where this fact appears with proof?  In [LLT] there is neither reference nor proof.

Answer (score 1):

The only place where I have seen this in the literature is by combining (15) on page 109 of Donkin's "The q-Schur algebra" with the usual results for the symmetric group which I assume can be found in Macdonald. Donkin doesn't consider the projective Grothendieck groups but once you have one isomorphism the Cartan pairing should give you the other.